# Table for MTF MA only shows exact data if open lower TF, but not for higher TF

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make a table that shows the close and moving average values for multi timeframes. I intended it to have `15m`, `H1`, `H4`, `D1`, and `W1`.

But my problem is, my code works as I wish only when I open the lowest time frame which is `15m`.

Whenever I open a higher time frame let say `H4`, the values for `H4`, `D1`, and `W1` works fine, but not for lower `tf` as in `H1` and `15m`.

Answer (score 0):

According to pinescript's user Manual, requesting lower than current chart's timeframe data using the **security()** function is not supported.
The chart consists of the current timeframe's OHLC values, the main problem with such a case is that some part of lower timeframe data will be inevitably lost, as it’s impossible to display it on a higher timeframe chart and not to break the time axis.